# Optimal Roth-type result in diophantine approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha$ be a real algebraic number. It is easy to see that if $\deg(\alpha) = 2$, that for there exists a number $c(D(\alpha))$, where $D(\alpha)$ is the discriminant of the primitive integral quadratic polynomial whose root is $\alpha$, such that

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right \rvert > \frac{c(D(\alpha))}{q^2}$$

for all rational numbers $p/q$ with $q > 0$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$. In view of Dirichlet's theorem, this is the best possible result.

In 1958 Klaus Roth proved the following stunning theorem, as a culmination of the approach invented by Axel Thue in 1909 and developed by many subsequent authors including Siegel and Dyson. He proved that for any algebraic number $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a number $c(\alpha, \varepsilon)$ such that for rational numbers $p/q$ with $q > 0$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ we have

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right \rvert > \frac{c(\alpha, \varepsilon)}{q^{2 + \epsilon}}.$$

The problem is that the dependence of $c(\alpha, \varepsilon)$ on either parameter is ineffective. Thus in many applications one has to use a qualitatively worse but effective version of Roth's theorem to get results. Lang also conjectured that one can replace the $q^\varepsilon$ term in the denominator with $(\log q)^{1 + \varepsilon}$. Indeed, if we take $\varepsilon = 1$ we can 'remove' the dependence on $\varepsilon$ completely.

I am asking about what is expected conjecturally, in view of the quality of result in the quadratic case. In particular, does one expect to be able to find a number $c(\alpha)$ such that

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right \rvert > \frac{c(\alpha)}{(q \log q)^2}$$

for all $p/q \in \mathbb{Q}, \gcd(p,q) = 1, q > 0$, and such that $c(\alpha)$ can be made to depend at most polynomially on the height of the algebraic number $\alpha$?

Comment: Perhaps a useful pointer: the article "Geometric Invariant Theory and Roth's Theorem" by Marco Maculan https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0926 has a discussion of the reason for the loss of effectiveness in section 1.1.4. Also, I believe this preprint has been incoporated in the SMF memoir https://smf.emath.fr/sites/default/files/2017-08/smf_mem-ns_152__sample.pdf

Comment: The ineffectivity is very simple to understand: Roth proves that 100 superb rational approximations are impossible. That’s enough for finiteness, but it certainly doesn’t imply that 1 isn’t possible. [Rest of comment split off due to character upper bound.]

Comment: Argh!! Apparently copy pasting doesn’t work in this app. Anyway the point is that you pass to a subsequence, guarantee the heights are well-spaced, etc., but fundamentally you must use the existence of many (well-spaced) approximations to reach a contradiction because of Roth’s Lemma. And Roth’s Lemma (or variants) is necessary because when you apply the polynomial method, so to speak, you can’t guarantee the polynomial you produce (that vanishes to high order somewhere) doesn’t vanish at another particular point. And that’s because you apply pigeonhole to produce it (Siegel’s Lemma).

Comment: @alpoge I am aware of all of these characteristics of Roth's argument. My question is really about what is a reasonable conjectured height bound for the largest possible solution... I was careful to phrase it in such a way that the lower bound *always* holds rather than the upper bound can only hold for *finitely many exceptions*

Comment: Indeed I’m aware —- I just put those comments up to try to explain the ineffectivity in a down to earth way in case a reader is scared away by the notation in the above link. Sorry!!!